# Shading in TikZ calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I’ve produced the calendar below with TikZ but I think the colourings need to be made more salient by shading a box around the coloured dates (as there will be four of these years on a page and the colouring gets drowned out).  How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}    
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\sffamily\scriptsize
\begin{center}
\makebox[0pt]{\tikz
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!60!black}
\calendar [dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31,
month list,month label left,month yshift=1.25em]
if (Sunday) [black!50]
% GROUP 1
if (between=2012-08-09 and 2012-08-12)[orange]
if (between=2012-06-01 and 2012-06-03)[orange]
if (between=2012-04-05 and 2012-04-07)[orange]
if (between=2012-12-22 and 2012-12-27)[orange]
% GROUP 2
if (between=2012-09-10 and 2012-09-15)[blue] 
if (between=2012-08-17 and 2012-08-21)[blue] 
if (between=2012-06-29 and 2012-07-02)[blue] 
if (between=2012-05-14 and 2012-05-21)[blue] 
% GROUP 3
if (between=2012-11-02 and 2012-11-09)[darkgreen] 
if (between=2012-01-01 and 2012-01-27)[darkgreen] 
;}
\end{center}
\end{figure}\end{document}
```

Comment: How can you do what? You could **a)** use another color, **b)** use a filling, **c)** use `\contour`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this be salient enough?

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\scriptsize
\tikz
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!60!black}
\calendar [
  dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31,
  month list, month label left, month yshift=1.25em,
  days={
    text width=width("00"),
    align=right,
    inner xsep=
      .5*\csname tikz@lib@cal@xshift\endcsname-.5*\csname tikz@text@width\endcsname,
    inner ysep=.5*\csname tikz@lib@cal@month@yshift\endcsname-.5*height("0")}
]
if (Sunday) [days={fill=black!50}]
% GROUP 1
if (between=2012-08-09 and 2012-08-12)[days={fill=orange}]
if (between=2012-06-01 and 2012-06-03)[days={fill=orange}]
if (between=2012-04-05 and 2012-04-07)[days={fill=orange}]
if (between=2012-12-22 and 2012-12-27)[days={fill=orange}]
% GROUP 2
if (between=2012-09-10 and 2012-09-15)[days={fill=blue,text=white}]
if (between=2012-08-17 and 2012-08-21)[days={fill=blue,text=white}]
if (between=2012-06-29 and 2012-07-02)[days={fill=blue,text=white}]
if (between=2012-05-14 and 2012-05-21)[days={fill=blue,text=white}]
% GROUP 3
if (between=2012-11-02 and 2012-11-09)[days={fill=darkgreen}]
if (between=2012-01-01 and 2012-01-27)[days={fill=darkgreen}]
;
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I won't grey fill the Sundays, but otherwise, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Why do I get an error message when I replace `\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}` with `\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage{tikz}`?  I'd prefer to stick with `article` as my document class for the moment.

Comment: The code that causes the error message is `days={ ... }`.  But, commenting it out, you get white space around single-digit days, instead of the continuous box you get with two-digit days.  A fast and nasty work around is to replace it with `day text=\%d0`, making all days two digits long.

Comment: @DanielHarbour The `standalone` class uses `article` internally; it is only used in my example to reduce the code to the TikZ example. I don’t get an error with `\documentclass[12pt]{article}\usepackage{tikz}`. What do you get? Feel free to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: Instead of `days={fill=darkgreen}` can we strike the day?

Comment: @alper `days={append after command=(\tikzlastnode.south west)edge(\tikzlastnode.north east)}` for example. Or you change the shape to `cross out` or `strike out` from the [`shapes.misc` library](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.shapes.misc).

Comment: How can I change the shape to `cross out`?